# Pygame scolling along a fixed path at variable speeds

Tags: python, scroll, pygame, custom-scrolling

I am trying to scroll a background along a fixed path (imagine a bike round a velodrome - 2x straights and 2x 180 degree bends) with a hero/sprite in the center of the screen.

I'm having trouble figuring out how I would do this with a variable speed input? (this stops me from creating a list of x and y coordinates - I think??)

I plan on adapting the code taken from this example code
[PyScroll](http://github.com/bitcraft/pyscroll/blob/master/tutorial/code/quest.py)

This code uses keys pressed that determines which way the background moves:
eg. key right pressed = current position(x or y coordinate) + speed * time difference.  This gives the new position.
Where speed is in pixels per second and the time difference is clock tick per frame.

At the moment I'm thinking up a set of rules to help determine the next self._position value in the code. For example if the background is in a certain position then the hero must be on the straight (adding only to say the y) or at the start of the corner (then a semi circle equation path kicks in).

This is seems like a strange way of doing it?  Is there a way to follow vectors factoring in the time differences caused by clocktick and variable speed input?

Comment: can you help me understand the question better. can you add some specific code snippets you have problems with .  If looking for some help on how to design your top level functions , then try to make a brief snippets of pyScroll code to help us understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still getting to grips with SO.  I guess I was looking for more of a conceptual answer rather than the code.

I solved it by using the clock.tick (the time elapsed since the last frame) to create a mini average speed. (dt =difference in time)

Using the current speed the last frame combined with dt I could give a distance to travel (new x y coordinates). Easy enough when traveling along the straight.

When the hero sprite got to the corner I used trig and a length of an arc equation to update the x y coordinates.

Putting the code in the key press function (def handle_input) was the wrong thing to do.  It worked in the def update of the hero class.